# Model names and namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Admin and I would like to create a namespace with the same name. When I do it `Admin is not a module` is raised. Is there a way how the specify the route or another way to solve this?

Admin is a Devise model.

the namespace in routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :buildings
end
```

And the controller `controllers/admin/buildings_controller.rb`

```
module Admin
  class BuildingsController < Admin::AdminController
    before_action :authenticate_admin!
```

Comment: Please, show us `routes.rb` fragment where you define the namespace and `buildings` path and the buildings controller definition (at least first few lines).

Comment: It has nothing to do with routes, the class Admin::Buildings Controller is not defined

Comment: your controller file name must match the class: **admin/buildings_controller.rb** -> `module Admin; class BuildingsController < AR; end; end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is not route-specific, but rather Ruby-specific.  A Rails model is a Ruby class.  You cannot have a `class` and a `module` with the same name, and in the same context.

What it sounds like you're after is [Devise's new Multi-User Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)?

Alternatively, what you can do is keep your custom administration controllers in a different namespace (like `Administration`) and route `/admin/buildings` CRUD to a your custom namespace:

```
scope path: "/admin", as: "admin", module: 'administration' do
  resources :buildings
end
```